# Dealing with multiple matches in adist

Tags: regex, r, string-matching

I would like to compute the number of character insertions before a character was matched in a string. I'm extracting the `"trafos"` attribute from the `adist()` function output to return the string of transformations. This works fine when there is only one instance of the character i'm interested in. For example,

```
attr(adist("r","world",counts=T),"trafos")
```

returns

```
     [,1]   
[1,] "IIMII"
```

Thus counting the number of "I"s before the "M" would give me my answer: 2

However, when there are multiple instances, the function for some reason only returns a match for the final instance. For example,

```
attr(adist("r","barry",counts=T),"trafos")
```

returns

```
     [,1]   
[1,] "IIIMI"
```

Is there any way I can get `adist()` to return "IIMMI" or at least "IIMII"? Perhaps another function or a option I need to turn on? Should I consider brewing my own function?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a particularly elegant solution but it might be good enough.

try

`parts <- strsplit("barry", "r")[[1]]`

`nchar(parts[1])`

EDIT:
I put this in a function.

```
nchar.before = function(before, string)
{
  parts = strsplit(string, before)

  return(as.numeric(lapply(parts, function(v) nchar(v[1]))))  
}
```

example:

```
strings = c("rabc", "abcr", "abcrabcr", "abcabc")
nchar.before(before = "r", string = strings)
```

Output: `0 3 3 6`
Note how it outputs the entire length of the string if "r" is not in it. You could easily modify this to instead produce an `NA` or something else.